# Upgrade my Symfony2 app to use composer

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I want to upgrade my app that I've developed with Symfony2 for users who want to use it do so with composer.

I don't know how to create composer.json file based on deps file.

This's my deps file: https://github.com/biruwon/Vecinos2.0/blob/master/deps

For example, what about with the bundles without composer.json? Or libraries how TCPDF upload on sourceforge?

If you help me here or with a pull request I'll be very thankful to you.

PD: I do this first and then update Symfony2 to Symfony2.1

Comment: Btw Symfony2.1 is still beta. Moving to composer is not difficult. Install composer and then go to http://packagist.org/ looking for the repo you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For TCPDF it's quite easy it is [on packagist already](http://packagist.org/packages/tcpdf/tcpdf).

For bundles or libs that are not on packagist, the best way is to first get it to work in your project using a [custom package repository](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2) in your composer.json, and once that's done sending a pull request to the original author with a composer.json and asking them to submit it to Packagist is the way to go.

Comment: I've a problem when install sonata-project/admin-bundle:[RuntimeException] The process timed out. and it's the same for update to Symfony2.1. I tried with COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=4000 php composer.phar install and doesn't work. What's the problem? If the problem is my connection, It would be nice to see the progress of cloned.

Comment: You can check https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/332 - it's not done yet, but hopefully one day we will have more reporting on that aspect

Comment: I solved it with COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=20000 because my connection's very slow. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Download the composer in symfony2 root folder:

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

and execute

```
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar update
```

use this if you can update to the last version.

Comment: It has nothing to do with this.